# Find all documents which lack a value across multiple indexed fields

Tags: solr

I understand how faceting in Solr works and have a basic understanding of the Solr query syntax, but I'm having trouble designing a facet query to get what I want. Here's the scenario:

I have a set of users that are all indexed in Solr. They have three fields:

1. invited tests - tests they have been invited to, but not yet taken
2. passed tests - tests they have taken and passed
3. failed tests - tests they have taken and failed

None of these fields overlap and contain independent sets of tests. I have facet queries written for these three fields which return the counts of the users who, for instance, have been invited to test x, test y, test z, etc, and similarly for passed and failed tests.

What I need now is a facet over those tests which exist neither in the invited, passed, or failed sets, that would produce a list of counts similar to the other facets, i.e. the count of users who have neither been invited to, nor passed, nor failed test x, y, z, etc. How would I construct a facet for this? And how could I write the filter query to retrieve the actual set of users that make up that facet count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert but could you not do something like:

-invitedtests:x AND -passedtests:x AND -failedtests:x

To find people that haven't been invited, passed or failed test 'x'?